# Images not showing with Expo/React Native and Next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, next.js, expo

So I am trying to use the Native Base Solito starter:

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/nativebase-templates/tree/master/solito-universal-app-template-nativebase-typescript

This is the first time I've tried to work with Next, and I am trying to get image support with Expo.

Per the Expo documentation:

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-nextjs/

I should be able to just use `next-image`, which I am doing:

```
const { withNativebase } = require('@native-base/next-adapter')
const withImages = require('next-images')

module.exports = withNativebase(
  withImages({
    dependencies: [
      '@expo/next-adapter',
      'next-images',
      'react-native-vector-icons',
      'react-native-vector-icons-for-web',
      'solito',
      'app',
    ],
    nextConfig: {
      projectRoot: __dirname,
      reactStrictMode: true,
      webpack5: true,
      webpack: (config, options) => {
        config.resolve.alias = {
          ...(config.resolve.alias || {}),
          'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
          '@expo/vector-icons': 'react-native-vector-icons',
        }
        config.resolve.extensions = [
          '.web.js',
          '.web.ts',
          '.web.tsx',
          ...config.resolve.extensions,
        ]
        return config
      },
    },
  })
)
```

Despite this, my images are just not displaying in Next. Elements are generated with the styling I am applying to the image elements, but the images themselves are **not** displaying.

I tried both universal routing import and direct path:

```
import GrayBox from 'resources/images/graybox.png'
import Car from '../../../../packages/app/resources/images/car.png'
```

As well as several different images uses:

```
<Image
  source={require('../../../../packages/app/resources/images/car.png')}
  style={{ width: 500, height: 750 }}
  alt="test"
/>

<Image
  source={GrayBox}
  key={index}
  style={{ width: 500, height: 750 }}
  alt="test2"
/>

<Image
  source={Car}
  key={index}
  style={{ width: 500, height: 750 }}
  alt="test3"
/>
```

None of these images are displayed.

I've tried both the react native image:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/image

As well as the native base wrapped one.

Still nothing.

Any clue what is wrong in my configuration to cause images to not show?

I suspect it's something in my `next.config.js`

**EDIT:**

If I add:

```
  plugins: [withImages, withFonts, [withExpo, { projectRoot: __dirname }]],
```

to my next.config.js, I get the following error:

```
../../packages/app/resources/images/cart_black.png
TypeError: unsupported file type: undefined (file: undefined)
```

Comment: What is the final generated `<img>` tag in the browser? Does an image file exist at that URL? Is it readable by the server process?

Comment: are there any error logs?

Comment: @kmoser No <img> tag generated. Maybe some weirdness due to React Native Web?

Comment: @ross None that reference the images

Comment: I haven't understood, you want to code in web by using ReactNative? @StevenMatthews

Comment: @AmerllicA Yeah, it's called React Native Web, and Expo supports it out of the box. It's a more and more common workflow.

Comment: Dear bro @StevenMatthews, I know what the RNW is, But your explanation isn't enough clear to be understood, please add a re-production of exact issue. I'm so excited to solve these kinds of problems. if adding re-production isn't straightforward please add the image issue screenshot, I want to know the shape of error, also please inspect and exactly copy the` img` tag that you expect to be showed and paste in your question post, these will help me a lot to say the corret solution.

Comment: Another question @StevenMatthews, are you using `import Image from 'next/image'`? Are those `<Image` in your question post the nextjs image component?

Comment: I am using the React Native image, per Expo's instructions:

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-nextjs/

Comment: There is no error with current build. If I enable withImages in a plugins array in next.config.js, I get this: ../../packages/app/resources/images/cart_black.png
TypeError: unsupported file type: undefined (file: undefined)

Comment: can you add reproducible GitHub example?

Comment: are images visible on the browser?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to solve my problem, if I add it to my next.config.js file:

```
plugins: [withImages, [withExpo, { projectRoot: __dirname }]],
  nextConfig: {
    images: {
      disableStaticImages: true,
    },
    ...
    }
```

Comment: That's because you're using the `next-images` plugin which conflicts with Next.js static image imports. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#disable-static-imports.

Comment: I'm using almost the exact same stack as you: React Native Web + NextJS and was having the exact same error. Can confirm this solution works. I also put a Github issue: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/4613 on the expo-cli repo, so anyone else having this issue can find the fix

Answer (score 1):

I need more information (that I have mentioned as comment) to say the exact solution but I guess two things:

1. You have used wrong prop to pass the image to the `<Image` component

   ```
   import SomeThingPng from '[/someWhere/something.png]';

   <Image
     src={SomeThingPng} // <= Don't use source
   ```

   Instead of using `source` use `src`
2. My second guess is your assets path loading that you have configured in the:

   ```
   nextConfig: {
      projectRoot: __dirname,
   ```

   Maybe you should some additional name to `__dirname` or use `basePath` for changing your **publicPath** of Webpack to correctly load your images in the browser with the correct image address. actually, my second guess is ***Wrong image path address***

Comment: @AmellicA - you absolutely should NOT use "src" instead of "source". This is NOT vanilla React. It is React Native Web. They work differently.

The correct prop for React Native Web is "source".

https://reactnative.dev/docs/image

I will look into projectRoot as a potential solution.

Comment: No @StevenMatthews, Instead of using RN Image, bring NextjsImage, you absolutely, can use an specific component just for Web. and for RN use what ever.