# React Can't import image, image "is not a valid image file"

Tags: reactjs, image, import, next.js

I'm trying to compile a project with some images. when i use yarn dev, i can compile almost everything but when it come to images, it will always give me the following error :

```
Error: Image import "../assets/images/banner-moc-1-1.png" is not a valid image file. The image may be corrupted or an unsupported format.
```

I don't undeerstand why it says that because my file is a classic png. i don't think that the issue come from the image.

I there something that i've missed ?

i'm using a next template. There was a problem when building where a type error happened. i've updated every packages in the packages.json to the latest version thinking it would work. Now it compile but it give me the error message you read above.

Comment: Are you using next.js?

Comment: The error usually occurs when your import path is wrong. Alternatively it could be that the project bundler (webpack usually) doesn't understand the file. If you set up the project with a template this shouldn't be the case.

Have you tried using different files / image file-types just to check if it is the file?

Comment: I do use next.js

Comment: Did you happen to make any progress? I happen to have a very very similar setup with the same exact error. I am also using nextjs and having a hard time using images. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74837692/nextjs-image-import-is-not-a-valid-image-file

Comment: Same, why there is no progress on this thread?

Comment: my import path is good. it happen with every image i try to import

Comment: @everyone I found a solution, you need to get edit your nextjs config file. See [here](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/4613)

Answer (score 1):

I found a nextjs config that worked for me:

```js
// @generated: @expo/next-adapter@2.1.52
// Learn more: https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-nextjs/

const { withExpo } = require("@expo/next-adapter");
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const withImages = require("next-images");
const withFonts = require("next-fonts");
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")(["react-native-web"]);

const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    disableStaticImages: true,
  },
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [withTM, withExpo, withImages, withFonts],
  nextConfig
);
```

[Here's](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/4613) my github issue

and [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73142566/images-not-showing-with-expo-react-native-and-next) where I found my answer (Steven Matthews)

Note: This was for my react native web + nextjs project. It should work but I don't know what to do if it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by putting the path to the image src attribute (`<Image src='/some-path' />`), removing all of the image imports (`import SomeImage from 'some-path'`)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your nextjs config.
You can also specify `remotePatterns` if you want to import pictures from other websites for development purposes otherwise if you don't you'll get an error.

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  images: {
    formats: ['image/webp'],
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: '**',
        port: '',
        pathname: '**',
      },
    ],
  }
}
```