# Image import is not a valid image file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, expo

#### Summary

I should expect my expo-react-native + nextjs app to build after installing and adding the 'next-images' plugin just like the docs say, but at build time I am stopped by 7 occurrences of the same exact error:

> "Error: Image import "./assets/X.png"

is not a valid image file. The image may be corrupted or an unsupported format." This error is found not only in my own code, but code from packages that I have installed **(specifically react-navigation)**

**### Environment**

> expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
> System:
> OS: Linux 5.15 Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 11 (bullseye)
> Shell: 5.1.4 - /bin/bash
> Binaries:
> Node: 16.17.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
> Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
> npm: 8.15.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
> Watchman: 20220528.183901.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
> npmPackages:
> expo: ^47.0.0 => 47.0.8
> react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0
> react-dom: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0
> react-native: 0.70.5 => 0.70.5
> react-native-web: ~0.18.7 => 0.18.10

```
Expo Workflow: managed
```

#### Please specify your device/emulator/simulator platform, model and version

> ChromeOS Version 102.0.5005.189 (Official Build) (64-bit) and
> CodeSandbox Projects: Latests browser version

#### Error output

> @react-navigation/elements:154 Error: Image import
> "./assets/back-icon-mask.png" is not a valid image file. The image may
> be corrupted or an unsupported format.
>
> ./AppbarBackIcon:66 Error: Image import
> "../../assets/back-chevron.png" is not a valid image file. The image
> may be corrupted or an unsupported format.

you get the idea

#### Reproducible demo or steps to reproduce from a blank project

[Link to repl](https://replit.com/@razorshnegax/exponext-image-error). This repl is my dev environment with all my code removed. The repl should run automatically when it boots. If not, run the command

> `cd north-sea-native-next/north-sea/next && yarn next dev`

and wait for the page to build and the error to appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using the Next/images plugin this nextjs config worked for me

```js
// @generated: @expo/next-adapter@2.1.52
// Learn more: https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-nextjs/

const { withExpo } = require("@expo/next-adapter");
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const withImages = require("next-images");
const withFonts = require("next-fonts");
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")(["react-native-web"]);

const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    disableStaticImages: true,
  },
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [withTM, withExpo, withImages, withFonts],
  nextConfig
);
```

[Here's](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/4613) my github issue

and [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73142566/images-not-showing-with-expo-react-native-and-next) where I found my answer (Steven Matthews)

Note: This was for my react native web + nextjs project. It should work but I don't know what to do if it doesn't